# Writing a recursive query and join with another list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, recursion

I am trying to display articles from database but I created recursive table for categories. So the problem is when parent category selected I am not able to retrieve articles from child categories.

```
public class Categories
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public int? parentId { get; set; }

    public IList<Categories> ChildMenu { get; set; }
}
```

and Article class as

```
public class Article
{

    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public int CategoryId{ get; set; }

   .... etc

}
```

I created this method to create a list of category recursive and join with article but it didn't work

```
private  IEnumerable<Categories> GetCatList(int category)
{
   return db.Categories.Where(x => x.parentId == category || x.id == category).Union(db.Categories.Where(x => x.parentId == category).SelectMany(y =>GetCatList( y.id)));
}
```

I used AsHierarchy

```
var a = db.Categories.ToList().AsHierarchy(e => e.id, e => e.parentId,category);

catModel = (from prod in ArticleList()
           join cats in a.ToList()
                on prod.Category equals cats.Parent.Category
               select prod).ToList();
```

again no success...

Please If anyone has solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following

```
public static void FindTree(int? parent,List<Category> list,ref List<Category> result)
    {
        if(list!=null && list.Count >0)
        {
            var details = list.Where(x=>x.ParentId == parent).ToList();
            foreach(var detail in details)
            {
                result.Add(detail);
                FindTree(detail.Id,list,ref result);
            }
        }

    }
```

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nincCO)

Note: this method will retrieve all the children tree and the parent node excluded , you can include it if you want.

hope it will help you